# Handling multiple IDs in Route

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

As far as I can understand, the conventional routing in .NET Core MVC is `[controller]/[action]/{id?}`

However, I have the following POST request I'm trying to catch which looks like this:

```
myDomain/MyController/MyAction/userID/anotherID/myInfo
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HTTPPost]
    [Route("MyAction/{userID:minlength(2)}/{anotherID:int}/myInfo")]
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromRoute] string userID, [FromRoute] int anotherID, [FromBody] string stuffIWant)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm not handling the routing correctly, but I'm not sure how I would get `userID` and `anotherID` from that route. I've published this action to my site, and tried to do a test post with the same URL, but didn't get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HTTPPost]
    [Route("MyAction/{userID:minlength(2)}/{anotherID:int}/myInfo")]
    public IActionResult MyAction(string userID, int anotherID, [FromBody]  string stuffIWant)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatted :). Check the answer